# Linked server strange performance issue on a client server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, linked-server

I have a strange problem with linked server on SQL Server machines. I have got a Master SQL Server and two identical Client SQL Server. On the client machines there is a linked server named MASTER. The client machines use this linked server to sync their data to master DB.

The problem is; A query is working very good on Client 1. However the same query is 20 times slower on Client 2 than first one. Machines are identical and the other situations seem normal. I think there is a network based problem, but not sure. By the way, data size is almost same on two machines.

My sample code is below. On Client 1 each print line shows 50-100 ms, but on Client 2 it shows 500-750 ms

```
declare @i int =0
declare @ID int 
declare @Start datetime
declare @End datetime

set @Start=getdate()

while (@i<10)
begin

        Select Top 1 @ID=ID from [MASTER].[MYDB].[dbo].SYNCDATA

        set @End=getdate()
        PRINT CAST(datediff(ms,@start,@End) as varchar)
        set @Start=getdate()

        RAISERROR ('', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT

        set @i=@i+1
end
```

If anyone has experienced a problem like this before, maybe give me some clue to solve the problem...

Thanks, in advance

Kenan

Comment: My experience with linked servers is that openquery is worth the extra time and effort.

Comment: Openquery may provide better results. But in this situation, i think result will not change. As i said, the same query performance is very different between two clients.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is ever identical in the physical universe :)
The two client machines may differ in memory or the network connection or maybe the SQL client driver's version, or a million other factors.
What about the location of the client servers. Are they in the same building, different cities, maybe they are connected via different routers and one is slower than the other. There are so many variables here that it would be impossible to debug without physical access.

Comment: All machines are in the same network and location and also machines are VMware.